# Issue when i try to setup request headers on GCE ingress for GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backend, google-kubernetes-engine, google-compute-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Hello guys I hope you can help me!

I'm trying to create a backend config and use the following configurations to enable HSTS

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-10T14:42:35Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: xxxx
  name: xxxx
  namespace: xxxxxx
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 10
    healthyThreshold: 1
    port: 5000
    requestPath: /health
    timeoutSec: 5
    type: HTTP
    unhealthyThreshold: 5
  customRequestHeaders:
   headers:
   - "X-Client-Region:{client_region}"
   - "X-Client-City:{client_city}"
   - "X-Client-CityLatLong:{client_city_lat_long}"
 customResponseHeaders:
   headers:
   - "hsts:True"
   - "hsts-include-subdomains: True"
   - "hsts-max-age: 28800"
```

but I'm getting the following error

unknown field "customResponseHeaders" in com.google.cloud.v1.BackendConfig.spec

Informations

apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#request_headers

I expect to have this issue solved and be able to use HSTS on my Backend configuration.

Comment: Would you mind to share more details like the full snippet of code you are using to create the backend? (remove any personal information), what doc are you following?

Comment: Hello! I updated the post!

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML file sintax was not correct, there was a missing space in line 24 as you can see below, try yourself at https://www.yamllint.com/.

[image: YamlLint]

Comment: Heyy, I found the issue, is regarding the K8S version that I was running in gke, this feature is only availabe on 1.25 and later.

Comment: I am glad to hear it worked, from my side it worked as I did the test in GKE version 1.27.3-gke.100.